# ubuntu 16.04 update gives segmentation fault

Tags: 16.04, apt, segmentation-fault

performing `sudo apt-get update` gives the following error:

```
** (appstreamcli:5640): WARNING **: No origin found for file packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/lucid/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/werner-jaeger/ppa-werner-vpn/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/werner-jaeger/ppa-werner-vpn/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
```

I've tried removing `cache/*.bin` and modifying `lists` but nothing has changed. `sudo apt-get upgrade` however is performed without any error. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The software sources mentioned in the error message should be removed. That's all.

Comment: @MichaelBay Do you mean `/usr/bin/appstreamcli`?

Comment: That and the "lucid" repo and all the others mentioned in the error message.

Comment: @MichaelBay won't removing them all generate more problems?

Comment: How so? The problem you're asking about is due to improper third party repositories that shouldn't be added in the first place, and nothing else. Adding non-official software sources should be done prudently. For starters, "lucid" means 12.04, it has no place in 16.04 (a leftover from a release upgrade?) and the "werner-jaeger" PPA is totally obsolete, has no packages for your release (and not updated since 2013!!), hence the 404 error.